# onclick handler doesn’t always run while child elements are being updated

Tags: javascript, html

I have a row of `<a>` elements which have `onclick` handlers:

```
<a onclick="selectCoin('MER');">
<div id="MER">
...
</div>
</a>
```

The interior of the `<div>` child gets overwritten continuously to update some text inside the buttons. The updating is done by querying the `#MER` selector, and assigning to `innerHTML`. I noticed that the `onclick` handlers don’t always run if the `<div>` element is being updated in the background. Oftentimes, I have to click it two or three times before the `onclick` hander actually gets invoked. If I make the `<div>` elements static, the `onclick` handlers run consistently and reliably.

Why does updating the `<div>` child cause the `onclick` handler to stop working consistently? How do I fix this issue, while still updating the contents of the button?

Comment: the onclick handler probably runs, it just doesn't work. so you'd need to show your js code

Comment: Please post the code having the issue, You posted that the code is not working after the div update. Please post a fiddle to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Considering setting `innerHTML` creates new button elements and new click handler functions, the behavior fails to surprise. You could try updating DOM content in JavaScript without replacing button elements at all.. If you need further assistance please supply code that [reproduces the problem in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (doing so will also help prevent getting your question closed).

Comment: @GarrGodfrey the onclick handler is just a `console.log` print, which does work 9 times out of 10. it’s the fact that it doesn’t work 100% of the time that’s the problem. i can’t really post a fiddle, since the application relies on a websocket server to send the updates. i tried mocking it up on jsfiddle with a while loop that just generates updates continuously, but that just caused the fiddle to freeze up, since there isn’t any delay between updates

Comment: @traktor `innerHTML` is only set on the *child* element (replacing the *grandchildren* of the `<a>` element), why would that interfere with the click handler on the parent element?

Comment: here’s a fiddle with the basic setup, but it’s missing the actual thing pushing the updates, since i couldn’t figure out a way to mock that without the actual websocket server: https://jsfiddle.net/vLe827n3/3/

Comment: it can be hard sometimes to tell in the console.log. duplicate outputs aren't shown unless you expand

Comment: @GarrGodfrey that’s not what’s happening, i know because in the real application, there is more than one button (they are supposed to be like tabs), and clicking a different button doesn’t always emit a new console message.

moreover, if i turn off the server pushing the updates, the buttons work 100% of the time.

Comment: I adjusted your fiddle to continuously update the DIV. I cannot reproduce a problem. https://jsfiddle.net/yqs9ft7n/

Comment: @GarrGodfrey thank you! but, **i can reproduce the problem**, at least on my browser (firefox 91). it seems more likely to show up if you click the text (as opposed to the empty area of the button), which probably makes sense…

Comment: yeah, to generate a `click` event, the browser needs a `mousedown` and then a `mouseup` on the same element. If the element goes away in between, no click

Comment: @GarrGodfrey changing the handler to an `onmousedown` handler fixed the problem! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate a click event, an element must receive a `mousedown` followed by a `mouseup`.

If the element goes away after the `mousedown` and is replaced with a new one, the click event is not sent.

You could do your own mousedown/mouseup detection on the `<a>` element, but if nothing inside the element is really clickable, you can disable mouse events on the child elements, so that they all occur on the `<a>` element

on your "MER" div:

`style="pointer-events:none;"`

Working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/8h17rcpz/

Answer (score 1):

`click` events are only generated if a `mousedown` and `mouseup` pair of events are fired consecutively on the same element, which is not going to happen if it gets swapped between down and up events.

The simplest solution would be to replace `onclick` in HTML source with `onmouseup`. What side effects or undesirable behavior that might produce is not possible to assess from the information provided.